# How to fix "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.models' "

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

I am trying to run the server but i keep getting this error. i don't know how to solve this error since am fairly new at python and django.

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\W\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_
inner
self.run()
  File "C:\Users\W\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\W\desktop\manuproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in w
rapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\W\desktop\manuproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\W\desktop\manuproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390,
 in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\W\desktop\manuproject\venv\lib\site- 
 packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 377,
 in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\W\desktop\manuproject\venv\lib\site- 
 packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72,
 in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\W\desktop\manuproject\venv\lib\site- 
 packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in c
 heck_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\W\desktop\manuproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in c
heck_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\W\desktop\manuproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in ch
eck
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\W\desktop\manuproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in _
_get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\W\desktop\manuproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 579, in ur
l_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", 
self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\W\desktop\manuproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in _
_get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\W\desktop\manuproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 572, in ur
lconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\W\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in im
port_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in 
_find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in 
_call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\W\Desktop\manuproject\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 22, 
in <module>
    path('^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\W\desktop\manuproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\W\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in im
port_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in 
_find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in 
_call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\W\Desktop\manuproject\mysite\blog\urls.py", line 3, in 
<module>
    from django.models import Post
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.models'
```

I expect the server to run but i keep getting the error. It was working perfectly till i updated the models.py file.
I am developing a simple web app with django.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `from myapp.models import Post`?

Comment: let me try that

Comment: It certainly worked. Thanks a lot for your help